# Trouble displaying image in python GUI

Tags: python

I am creating a GUI in python. I created different frames using classes, and each page has a designated class. I am trying to display a simple image but the image doesn't display, even though I get no errors.

Comment: Please provide at least reproducible code

Comment: Make sure you store a reference to the image somewhere, so that it does not get garbage collected. That is a very common problem for new coders.  The fix can be as simple as `frame.image = myimage`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to save a reference to your image, so that it does not get garbage collected.

Something like:

```
myframe.img = myimage
```

You can add the image as an attribute to an existing object, like above, or

```
root.images = {}
root.images[str(myframe)] = myimage
```

You just need to store a reference to the image so that the Python garbage collector will not try to dispose of it.  Just putting it into a frame or a button is actually not enough to protect the image.